# Why does my random number generator always give me one?

Tags: javascript, random

I'm working on a project that will give me a random town wealth depending on what number is randomly generated. Yet whenever I press the "establish township" button, I always get "wealthy". How can I fix my code to enable desired results?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
h1 {font-size: 20pt; color: red;}
    p {font-size: 17pt; color: blue;}
    p2 {font-size: 18pt; color: orange;}
    p3 {font-size: 18pt; color: green;}
</style>
<p>This program will create a random town upon the click of a button.</p>

<button onclick="numberdescription()">Establish Township</button>
<br /><br /><br />
<p3 id="random"></p3>

<script>

function numberdescription() {
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1)
    if (num = 1) {
        desc = "wealthy";
    } else if (num = 2) {
        desc = "middle wealth";
    } else {
        desc = "dirt poor";
    }
document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = desc;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're comparing with `=` (assignment) intead of `==` (comparison). Thus the `if` predicate sets `num` to `1` when it is executed.

Comment: Obligatory JavaScript one-liner: `document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = ["wealthy", "middle wealth", "dirt poor"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];`. The real question though is why are there an equal number of dirt poor and wealthy towns?

Answer (score 2):

`=` is considered an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators). You want the equality operator `==`, which is a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

```
function numberdescription() {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1)
    if (num == 1) {
        desc = "wealthy";
    } else if (num == 2) {
        desc = "middle wealth";
    } else {
        desc = "dirt poor";
    }
    document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = desc;
}
```

Comment: It's "considered" an assignment operator because it *is* an assignment operator :)

Answer (score 0):

A single = sign assigns a value, thus you are assigning num a value of 1 with this code

```
num = 1
```

Replace the single = with double ==.

```
num == 1
```

Here is a list of [JavaScript comparison and logical operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).